# Getting public file url from customobject

Tags: java, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have a custom object class with a `File` type field, after I query the class, I do not get a public url to the file in the field. How can I get the full public url of a `File` field type from CustomObject class to be loaded in a ListView? I have an image loading library already by means of Picasso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
https://api.quickblox.com/data/<Class_name>/<record_id>/file?field_name=<field_name>&token=<qb_session_token>
```

more info here http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Download_file

Comment: Let me have a look into that, and thanks for the reply.

Comment: Using this url and plugin my own values does work, there should be a note of this on the API specific documentation about accessing `File` field objects when queried just for clarity since only the id for the file is returned from the query normally.